# Behavior of C++ const static after program termination

Tags: c++, static, exit

I have a program which creates a thread (I am using C++ Boost library for creating threads) when started. In the main program I have registered my cleanup function as.

```
atexit(cleanExit)
// Trap some signals for a clean exit.
signal(SIGQUIT, signalled)
signal(SIGABRT, signalled)
signal(SIGTERM, signalled)
signal(SIGINT, signalled)

static void signalled(int signal)
{
    exit(signal)
}
static void cleanExit(void)
{
     thread->interrupt();
     thread->join();
}
```

As you can see above during the clean exit process I interrupt the thread and then wait here (in the main process) so that the thread does its clean up stuff. When I call thread->interrupt, my thread gets interrupted and I do the thread cleanUp stuff. Till here everything is working smooth and there is no problem.

But the problem comes in when I call the cleanup function in the thread. In the cleanup function I am sending some status back to a server, for that I have created a utility function, In this utility function I am accessing a "const static string" member of the class. The problem is when I access this const static string my application got just stuck. I have checked with strace and I am getting a Seg Fault. But when I change this "const static string" to "const string" my cleanup goes smooth.

QUESTION
What is the behavior of C++ "const static" once the program is terminated. Do they giveup when exit is called (which can be seen in above case) or any thoughts on this behavior.

## UPDATE # 1

Here is the thread handler function. As I have mentioned above its a Boost thread.

```
try {
    while ( true ) {
        // Do your job here.
        // 1: We can be interrupted.
        boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
    }
}
catch (boost::thread_interrupted const& )
{
    // Before exiting we need to process all request messages in the queue
    completeAllWorkBeforeExiting();
}
```

When the main program calls thread->interrupt, the thread will raise thread_interrupted exception at # 1, and catching this exception I am doing my cleanup stuff.

Answer (score 2):

`const` does not affect when any object is destroyed.

`static` objects are destroyed in the order opposite to their order of creation. `atexit` essentially creates an anonymous `static` object with the given function as its destructor. That is, `static` object destructors and `atexit` callbacks occur in the order opposite their construction/registration.

It's completely unsafe to call `exit` from a signal handler. All the signal handler is practically allowed to do is set a flag which is later polled by the threads. As you've mentioned, the signal handler runs at interrupt time, so it might interrupt a system call. It might interrupt `malloc` in such a way that bypasses `malloc`'s multithreading locks, since the reentrancy is on the same thread, not a different one as usually happens.

So that's a source of all sorts of unpredictable behavior. Without seeing more, I can't be more specific about what effect `static` is having, but it probably has something to do with changing the object's lifetime and/or instantiating it once per object.

Comment: Thanks, I have provided an Update to my actual question. Considering this can you please elaborate why it is unsafe to call exit from signal handler.

Comment: Potatoswatter - Re *`static objects` are destroyed after `atexit` handlers run, in the order opposite to their order of creation.* - That's only true if all of the `atexit` handlers were registered after entry into `main`. Things get a bit messier for functions registered with `atexit` from within the dynamic scope of a constructor of a static object.

Comment: @FarrukhArshad - Calling `exit` from within the dynamic scope of a signal handler results in undefined behavior. Per C99, the *only* library functions that can be called from within the dynamic scope of a signal handler are `_Exit` and `abort`.

Comment: @DavidHammen Oh, really I'm completely wrong. Thanks for reminding me, I'll fix the answer.